# C# nested property pattern expression

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

Is it possible to do pattern matching on type and sub/nested properties at the same time?

E.g. something like the following:

```cs
// Something like this would be nice
if (person is Person { Pet { Name: { } name2 }})
{
    Console.WriteLine(name2);
}
```

With class structure as follows

```cs
public class Person
{
    public object? Pet { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    object person = GetPerson();

    // Example of current matching
    if(person is Person p && p.Pet is Pet pet && pet.Name is { } name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
    
    // Sample inline method
    Person? GetPerson()
    {
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

Wondering if those 3 checks can be done in 1 line, without needing intermediary variables saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# 8 it's possible. Credits to Rider which suggested to refactor it as:

```
if(person is Person {Pet: Pet {Name: { } name}})
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Starting from C# 8, there is [Recursive Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#patterns) in language.

Comment: Resharper basically taught me pattern expressions (and LINQ) through its suggestions

Comment: Couldn’t you drop the type Pet in …{Pet: Pet {…

Comment: didn’t notice that the class person’s member pet is of type object and not pet, so the pattern matching needs the type

Comment: For some reason, my R# or Rider wasn't showing how to convert, and googling failed no great attempts. Thanks!